# 'IOrderedeQueryable<Condominium>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

como na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nessa parte do Código:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Condominium>> FindCondominiumAllAsync()
{
    return await FindAll()
            .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
            .ToListAsync();
}
```

> 'IOrderedQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IOrderedQueryable'

Saberiam me auxiliar aonde estou errando ?

Retorno do FindAll:

```
 IQueryable<TEntity> FindAll();
```

Att.

Matheus.

Comment: o que retorna o `FindAll()`?

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta @LeandroAngelo

Answer (score -1):

Instale o `EntityFramework`.

O `ToListAsync` é um método de extensão definido na `classe System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions`

Você provavelmente não está importando o namespace ...

por exemplo `using System.Data.Entity;`